# MySQL replacing column type on table creation

Tags: mysql, column-types

I'm running a MySQL server, all is fine and well, but now I have an application running that is creating tables every now and then.

The application is creating tables in which one (or more) columns are defined as tinyint(3). For legacy purposes, I'd like to have these tables defined as smallint(5) instead.

As a workaround Im running a script every minute now, that replaces a single instance of a tinyint(3) column with a smallint(5) column.

```
    select @a := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE myDatabase.`', table_name, '` CHANGE `', column_name, '` `', column_name, '` SMALLINT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;') qry from information_schema.columns
    where table_schema = 'myDatabase'
      and column_type like '%tinyint%'
    order by table_name,ordinal_position
    ;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @a;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

One of the downsides is that this script only modifies a single column at a time, and produces an error if there is no tinyint column.

Is there not some more elegant way of replacing the tinyint(3) columns with smallint(5) columns?

With kind regards,
Marcel

Comment: How about changing the code that creates the tables?

Comment: I'm afraid that I do not have access to the sourcecode of the application.

Comment: And what "legacy purposes" are you trying to serve? The reason I ask is changing representations underneath a running application that you don't have source for is very likely to cause/uncover bugs in that third party application.

Comment: Since the enabling of this script one month ago we have not yet found any issues. The application logs changes where in a vanilla environment the change ID's don't go over 250, but in the modded environment they go over 9000, and the 10000 is in reach soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least fix the errors:

```
set @a := '';
select @a := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE myDatabase.`', table_name, '` CHANGE `', column_name, '` `', 
                     column_name, '` SMALLINT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;') qry
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'myDatabase'
  and column_type like '%tinyint%'
order by table_name, ordinal_position
limit 1;

if @a <> ''
then
    PREPARE stmt FROM @a;
    EXECUTE stmt;
end if;
```

With a bit more work, you could change all the columns in a single table with one `alter` statement, but that effort may not be worth it.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed solves part of the question. Replacing all the columns at once is not needed for now, as this is only a now-and-then issue, and we can afford it to wait 3 minutes after table creation. I'm waiting to see if someone can reply to the trigger part of the question, where it is automatically executed. If not, I'll mark your post as answer.